# Hebrew Unicode to Integer Conversion VBA

Tags: vba, unicode, hebrew

I am trying to convert the following Hebrew Unicode into its integer equivalence using VBA:

בּ

Technically speaking, this composition is made of ב and ּ    (a letter and a vowel)

using AscW(), I get 1488 for the letter and 1468 for the vowel if I do them SEPARATELY. However, if they are combined as in בּ, how can I get it's equivalent value? I want to get 1488 and 1468. When I use the AscW(), I am getting -1231, which is not good.

Comment: not sure why but I am getting a 1489 for `AscW()`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. alef = 1488, bet = 1489, ... :) Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Technically,

```
ChrW(64305)
= בּ

Cell A1 = "בּ"
AscW(Range("A1").value) 
= -1231

-1231 + 65536 = 64305
```

Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function from ADODB Stream, and then do a char on it. I think that should work: (You need to reference the latest Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library)

Public Function CorrectHebrew(gibberish As String) As String

```
Dim inStream As ADODB.stream

Set inStream = New ADODB.stream
inStream.Open
inStream.Charset = "WIndows-1255"
inStream.WriteText gibberish
inStream.Position = 0
inStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
CorrectHebrew = inStream.ReadText
inStream.Close
```

End Function

Answer (score -1):

> When I use the AscW(), I am getting -1231, which is not good.

It's sort of right. It's a known quirk of the `AscW` function that it returns UTF-16 code units misinterpreted as signed 16-bit numbers. If you add `&H10000` to bring it back into positive you get `&HFB31`, which is what you would expect for the combined ‘בּ’ aka U+FB31 Hebrew Letter Bet with Dagesh.

> I want to get 1488 and 1468

To get from composed form (U+FB31) to decomposed form (U+05D1, U+05BC) you would use the Unicode normalisation algorithm. Unfortunately VBA has no support for Unicode normalisation. If you can get to VB.NET it's easy there:

```
some_string.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
```

Comment: I think the question is on VBA

Comment: Yeeeees, I am aware of that. ‘Unfortunately VBA has no support for Unicode normalisation...’

Comment: therefore your answer doesn't really answer the question this is why i've downvoted... sorry

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will read about the subject that @mehow sent me and try his code. Thank you guys,

Comment: @mehow: neither does your answer, because there isn't a way of doing in pure VBA (short of writing your own implementation of the normalisation algorithm). Your code does nothing more than “add &H10000” as already said.